# how to set asset publisher tag with hard coded

Tags: liferay, assets

I added an asset publisher to liferay and add it to "portal-normal.vm" with "Portlet Id".

But this portlet (added with portlet Id to my theme) Does not inherit that portlet settings.

Now I want to set asset publisher tag with hard code, but I don't know how do it.

```
#set ($VOID = $velocityPortletPreferences.setValue('display-style', '1'))
#set ($VOID = $velocityPortletPreferences.setValue("portlet-setup-show-borders", "false"))
#set ($instanceId = '6nro')
#set ($myPortletId = "101_INSTANCE_${instanceId}")
#set ($portletSetup = $portletPreferencesFactoryUtil.getLayoutPortletSetup($layout, $myPortletId))
$theme.runtime($myPortletId, $queryString, $velocityPortletPreferences.toString())
$velocityPortletPreferences.reset()
```